# Unable to recreate a mongo index with the same name

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I have an index which i need to modify.

```
    {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "expectedDateTime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "expectedDateTime_1",
    "ns" : "expectation.expectation_data",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 43200
}
```

The expireAfterSeconds is incorrect and needs to be changed to 432000.

When I dropped the index it seemed fine

```
db.expectation_data.dropIndex({"expectedDateTime":1})
{ "nIndexesWas" : 4, "ok" : 1 }
```

The getIndexes() shows that the index does not exist.

Then when i try to recreate the index i get this error

```
db.expectation_data.createIndex({"expectedDateTime":1}, 
{expireAfterSeconds:432000,name:"expectedDateTime"});
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Index with name: expectedDateTime already exists with different options",
    "code" : 85
}
```

Now on running getIndexes(), i see that the index seems to have recreated with the old TTL. I tried repeating this process multiple times, but ran into the same issue again and again.

I cannot find any documentation which says that i cannot recreate an index of the same name. If i use a different name it works fine

```
db.expectation_data.createIndex({"expectedDateTime":1}, {expireAfterSeconds:432000});
.
.
>db.expectation_data.getIndexes()
.
.
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "expectedDateTime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "expectedDateTime_1",
    "ns" : "expectation.expectation_data",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 432000
}
```

Is there any restriction on recreating indexes with the same name ?

Comment: This looks like the index is recreated automatically (maybe a running background process or clients connecting to MongoDB which call ensureIndex programmatically?)

Comment: @Matt - As you expected. I just figured it out and posted the answer a couple minutes ago.

Comment: If you want, post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the index is recreated automatically after deletion. Make sure that no applications using `ensureIndex` or `@Index`-Annotations are connecting to the database.

Answer (score -1):

As it turned out. This was due to an @Index annotation used in the entity with the old timeout. The application was still running when i made the index changes.

When i stopped the application, i was able to create the index as i originally expected